# Installing messes up resolution

Tags: display, graphic-drivers, graphics, resolution

and thanks for reading my question.
(Before posting I checked many other questions on this forum, as well on other websites.)
Recently I booted a live elementary OS Loki image on an old laptop to try the OS out and I decided to install it.
Before installing, my display wasn't detected but the resolution was automatically set 1280*720, which is the ideal resolution for my screen.
However, since I installed the OS the default resolution became 640*480 (4:3) and the display remains undetected.
I cannot change it using the provided GUI (System Settings>Display), and I also tried to change it by using xrandr on the terminal but I found this quest to be fruitless.

I thought it could be a problem with my old laptop's graphics driver (Silicon Integrated Systems), since it appears it's support for linux has long been discontinued, and I also tried various methods for fixing this.

However, it still puzzles me how everything (resolution-wise) worked perfectly before the install. I even copied the kernel drives once from the live ISO image to my HDD in hopes the required drivers/the method through which the resolution was working would pass on to my installation...but that didn't work either (had to reinstall everything afterwards).

I was hoping there was a way to reproduce the same effects I have when I boot from the live USB to when I boot from the HDD, if more advanced things such as getting the OS to recognize my screen don't work.

If you know of a possible solution, please let me know. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find out how to correct this and I will leave it here for future reference for those who might be having similar issues.
I just followed the answer posted here https://askubuntu.com/questions/455888/low-resolution-on-lubuntu-14-04-sis

"force the machine to use the vesa driver.

Create a file /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/use-vesa.conf with the following content:

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "Configured Video Device"
  Driver "vesa"
EndSection
```

And that's all. Reboot, and you should have your resolution."

Answer (score 0):

please try ....

- at the grub boot
- add the option nomodeset
- then boot

Comment: Hi George.
Thanks for your suggestion.
I tried to do what you told me as shown in this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu (user: fossfreedom)
However when I booted everything looked the same and still wasn't able to change the resolution through the GUI. Perhaps I missed something?